# Proof that for $a>0$ and $a + 1/a$ element of $\mathbb{Z}$, $a^n + 1/a^n$ is always element of $\mathbb{Z}$ by induction

Tags: induction

Question is in the title. I'd like to prove that for $a>0$ ($a$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}$) and $a + 1/a$ an element of $\mathbb{Z}$, $a^n + 1/a^n$ is always element of $\mathbb{Z}$ by induction.

Comment: Correchtion  a^n + 1/(a^n)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$a^{k+1}+\frac{1}{a^{k+1}}=\left(a^{k}+\frac{1}{a^k}\right)\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)-\left(a^{k-1}+\frac{1}{a^{k-1}}\right)$$

Comment: Sort of reminds me of $\cos((n+1)x) = 2\cos(nx)\cos(x)-\cos(n-1)x$.

Comment: How kann I show that (a^(k-1)+1/(a^(k−1)) element of Z

Comment: You assume that by the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Well, I assume (a^(k+1)+1/(a^(k+1)) is it the same?

Comment: @Mark You assume $a^k+\frac{1}{a^k}\in\Bbb Z$ and $a^{k-1}+\frac{1}{a^{k-1}}\in\Bbb Z$. For the base case, note $a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}=\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^2-2$.