# Show that these two identities are equivalent

Tags: trigonometry, recurrence-relations

As an answer to the question
[Proof that for $a>0$ and $a + 1/a$ element of $\mathbb{Z}$, $a^n + 1/a^n$ is always element of $\mathbb{Z}$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505213/a0-a-1-a-in-mathbbz-implies-an-1-n-in-mathbbz-by-induction),
user236182
gave this answer:

$$a^{k+1}+\frac{1}{a^{k+1}}=\left(a^{k}+\frac{1}{a^k}\right)\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)-\left(a^{k-1}+\frac{1}{a^{k-1}}\right)
$$

This identity
made me think of this one:

$\cos((n+1)x) = 2\cos(nx)\cos(x)-\cos(n-1)x$.

Show that these two identities are equivalent.

(This is a result
neither deep nor profound.)

Comment: They do look alike, but I do not think there is any kind of equivalence between those two.

Comment: It is enough to set $a = e^{ix}$. Assuming you're aware of that, what is the point of asking?

Comment: I thought it was cute. Where is a good place to show interesting results that are not significant enough to publish?

Comment: A trivial fact.  $\cosh((n+1)x) = 2 \cosh(nx) \cosh(x) - \cosh((n-1)x)$ also fits. :-)